# Cells disappear when connecting to custom class

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a static cell UITableViewController in a UINavigationController in a UITabBarController.

When I create a custom class for UITableViewController and set it, all cells in UITableView disappear after build. I can see them in designer but not in Simulator nor device.

I'm new to iOS developing so forgive if I'm making an obvious mistake.

Comment: Maybe I should set custom class for UINavigationController instead of UITableViewController but how can I add properties if so?

Comment: Show the code for your subclass.

Comment: I found out, your guess was right. The methods automatically added by Xcode prevent my static cells to be shown. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To everyone who have the same struggle. It doesn't matter if you have the UITableViewController in a UINavigationController or not, after creating custom class you should comment or delete the following methods if you have static cells:

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 0
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return 0
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath)

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell
}
```